# controller not found laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5, controller

> ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
>   
> Class App\Http\Controllers\admin\FotoAlbumController does not exist

I've create my controller with this command:

```
php artisan make:controller admin\\FotoAlbumController --resource
```

But, it can't find my controller when i submit it with my form. here's my forms code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'admin/detailalbum', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'files' => true]) !!}
        <input type="hidden" name="id_album" value="{{$album->id}}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="foto" class="col-md-4 control-label">Photo</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="file" id="foto" name="foto" value="{{ old('foto') }}" required>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 control-label">Caption</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <textarea id="caption" name="caption" class="form-control" required>{{ old('caption') }}</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

Here's my routes.php:

`Route::resource('admin/detailalbum', 'admin\\FotoAlbumController');`

And here's my controllers code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Session;
use Validator;
use App\DetailAlbum;

class FotoAlbumController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $requestData = $request->all();
        $noo = 'admin/album/'.$request['id'];
        $rules  = [
            'foto' => 'required|mimes: jpg, jpeg, png, gif',
            'caption' => 'required',
        ];

        $validasi = Validator::make($requestData, $rules);

        if ($validasi->fails()) {
            return back->withErrors($validasi)->withInput();
        } else {
            $extension = $request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $extension;

            $request->file('foto')->move($uploadPath, $fileName);
            $requestData['foto'] = $fileName;

            DetailAlbum::create($requestData);
            Session::flash('success', 'Berhasil menambahkan Foto pada album tersebut.');

            return redirect($noo);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Is that something wrong with my code?

PS: i've already use 
`composer dumpautoload` and `php artisan clear-compile`

Comment: Why are you using double backlash "\\"  here `Route::resource('admin/detailalbum', 'admin\\FotoAlbumController');` ? Can you try to remove 1 ?

Comment: Its work perfectly for me?

Comment: As said by _EddyTheDove_ you are adding extra `\\`. Remove it and the not found issue needs to be disappeared.

Comment: Thank you very much. But it's not the problem. Coz it works 100% for another route resource controller.